# OpenCart Client Session Expiring

Tags: php, apache, opencart, centos7, plesk

After changing our clients OpenCart (2.0.3.1) website to a new CentOS 7 + Plesk 17 server, their customers are being logged off after a period of inactivity (about 1 hour). As far as I'm aware, OpenCart doesn't auto log out shopping cart users and it's reported as new.

The php session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0 and in fact the rest of the PHP session settings are the same as the old ISPConfig server.

What could be causing this... has anyone else had a similar Apache/PHP configuration issue?

- CentOS 7 on AWS
- Plesk Onyx 17.0.17
- PHP 7.1
- MySQL (5.5.52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an issue here that explains the issue and a solution.

https://websavers.ca/plesk-php-sessions-timing-earlier-expected/

Basically the /etc/cron.hourly/plesk-php-cleanuper is running and clearing the sessions every hour and not picking up the correct cookie_lifetime and gc_maxlifetime settings.

Moving plesk-php-cleanuper to /etc/cron.daily/ resolves the issue.

```
mv /etc/cron.hourly/plesk-php-cleanuper /etc/cron.daily/
```